# Cannot install bcrypt node.js module on Centos Server

Tags: node.js, centos, npm, bcrypt

I'm trying to install bcrypt on CentOS server but I got the following error:

```
info postuninstall bcrypt@0.5.0
ERR! bcrypt@0.5.0 install: `make build`
ERR! `sh "-c" "make build"` failed with 2
ERR!
ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.5.0 install script.
ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
ERR! not with npm itself.
ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
ERR!     make build
ERR! You can get their info via:
ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
ERR!
ERR! System Linux 2.6.18-028stab095.1
ERR! command "nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "bcrypt"
ERR! cwd /root/grouplo
ERR! node -v v0.6.15
ERR! npm -v 1.1.16
ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
ERR! message bcrypt@0.5.0 install: `make build`
ERR! message `sh "-c" "make build"` failed with 2
ERR! errno {}
```

What Can I do to solve this?
Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the same issue doing npm install bcrypt.
The other option is to install it from source.

```
git clone git://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js.git
cd node.bcrypt.js
node-gyp configure
node-gyp build
```

Rename the node.bcrypt.js folder to bcrypt, and move it into your node_modules of your project.

You can install node-gyp by doing npm install -g node-gyp (-g installs it globally).

Comment: I think openssl was missing in my system. After installing my problem solved

Comment: For me this didn't work until I'd installed other pre-requisites which enabled npm install to work just fine anyway. However you certainly gave me a clue in which direction to go. So I'll upvote you and post an alternative answer.

Answer (score 14):

There is also a native-js version of bcrypt which does not require compiling.
https://github.com/shaneGirish/bcrypt-nodejs

```
npm install bcrypt-nodejs
```

The api is very similar to the compiled version. The following is taken directly from the readme

### Basic usage:

Synchronous

```
var hash = bcrypt.hashSync("bacon");

bcrypt.compareSync("bacon", hash); // true
bcrypt.compareSync("veggies", hash); // false
```

Asynchronous

```
bcrypt.hash("bacon", null, null, function(err, hash) {
    // Store hash in your password DB.
});

// Load hash from your password DB.
bcrypt.compare("bacon", hash, function(err, res) {
    // res == true
});
bcrypt.compare("veggies", hash, function(err, res) {
    // res = false
});
```

Comment: bcrypt is a headache, I'm migrating to this. Thanks for the alternative.

Answer (score 7):

For me the answer was to ensure that I had gcc, openssl and node-gyp installed.

To install gcc and openssl, use yum:

```
sudo yum install gcc-c++ openssl-devel
```

To install node-gyp (globally), use npm:

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

Then the npm install of bcrypt worked just fine on centos

Answer (score 2):

Pre-built binaries are usually available for bcrypt in a few hours after a new release of bcrypt or after a few days after a new NodeJS version is released.

However, remember that binaries are only provided as a convenience.

If you see an error such as:

`You need the following packages on CentOS / RHEL / Fedora

- `gcc-c++` - In order to install a compiler chain to compile the node modules.
- `make` - To run the generated Makefile by node-gyp, which invokes compilers in order
- `python` - RHEL and CentOS come with the required version of python installed

Make sure all dependencies are installed with this command,

`yum install -y gcc-c++ make`

and then proceed with the bcrypt installation.

For other systems see: https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/wiki/Installation-Instructions

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, it turned out that my `node` wasn't compatible with `bcrypt`. I was using node version lts `12` but my bcrypt version in `package.json` was `5`, which must be `3`.

You can check the compatibility of node and bcrypt different versions [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#user-content-version-compatibility).

Hope it helped someone