# bcrypt not installing on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, npm, bcrypt

**I tried to install `bcrypt` in Ubuntu but got following error. I can't understand error message properly.**  Here is some discussion regarding to the same problem : https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js/issues/90 but still no solution found.

I have also tried to update npm(`npm install -g npm`) and installing the bcrypt with no luck.

```
isha@isha-ubuntu:~/Documents/xpressnepal$ sudo npm install
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bcrypt/0.7.7
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bcrypt/0.7.7
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings/1.0.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings/1.0.0

> bcrypt@0.7.7 install /home/isha/Documents/xpressnepal/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: "pre" versions of node cannot be installed, use the --nodedir flag instead
gyp ERR! stack     at install (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/install.js:65:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.self.commands.(anonymous function) [as install] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js:66:37)
gyp ERR! stack     at getNodeDir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:150:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:93:9
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:694:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:107:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:817:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:884:5)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-19-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/isha/Documents/xpressnepal/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v0.11.11-pre
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! bcrypt@0.7.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.7.7 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-19-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/isha/Documents/xpressnepal
npm ERR! node -v v0.11.11-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.26
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/isha/Documents/xpressnepal/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
isha@isha-ubuntu:~/Documents/xpressnepal$
```

Comment: is it possible for you to use a more 'stable' version of node.js ? You might also want to try installing the `bcrypt` package locally instead of globally. It might be possible that you are missing some libraries that `bcrypt` requires. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/20895568/732396

Comment: @yanhan thanks a lot , I get rid of this problem after installing the stable version of node as you suggested.

Comment: good to know you've solved your problem. I've added my comment as an answer; if you're kind enough to award me the answer, I thank you in advance

Comment: Updating npm helped me solve this issue `sudo npm update -g npm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try installing `bcrypt` with a more stable version of node.js . It might be also possible that you are missing some libraries that `bcrypt` requires, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20895568/732396

Answer (score 4):

Use the latest stable version of node.js. bcrypt hasn't been ported to node 0.11.x.

If you are using a git clone, simply cd into the tree and checkout 0.10.26-release:

```
git checkout v0.10.26-release
fetch
```

Then configure, make, and install as usual. Then try installing bcrypt again:

```
npm install -g bcrypt
```

Credit goes to yanhan. He pointed me in the right direction. I just wanted to post the specific commands that would fix it.

Comment: I had the same problem using Node v0.10.28. Used NVM to switch to v0.10.26 and bcrypt installed without a hitch.

Answer (score 1):

i have same problem but i fixed it

i used instead of npm yarn

yarn is package manager like npm

first install yarn your system then use this command to install bcrypt

> yarn add bcrypt

Answer (score 1):

TO install bcrypt on ubuntu current version
bcrypt
required to install-> node-pre-gyp

after install installing required

try cmd->sudo npm install bcrypt

Answer (score 0):

Change you node version from **0.11.x** to **0.10.x** as **bcrypt** is not ported into **0.11.x.**

if you have **n** (node version manager) installed then run:

**n 0.10.x**
(e.g x=26 or x=24 etc.)

Then run:

**npm install bcrypt**

inside your project directory.
To install **n** run

**npm install n**

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem. Nothing worked, but what managed to do the trick was installing `bcryptjs` instead of `bcrypt`.