# Error installing bcrypt with npm

Tags: node.js, npm, bcrypt

I'm unable to install [`bcrypt`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) using `npm` on my machine because I encounter the following errors. I have been troubleshooting the issue without much luck. Can you recommend any steps to diagnose or fix the problem so I can run `npm install bcrypt` successfully?

```
Someones-Macbook:node_modules Cody$ npm install bcrypt
npm WARN package.json grunt-contrib-htmlmin@0.1.3 No README data
|
> bcrypt@0.7.7 install /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/richintime/ultimate-seed/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

child_process: customFds option is deprecated, use stdio instead.
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:118:18: error: no member named 'Dispose' in 'v8::Persistent<v8::Function, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function>
      >'
        callback.Dispose();
        ~~~~~~~~ ^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:202:19: error: unknown type name 'uv_work_t'
void GenSaltAsync(uv_work_t* req) {
                  ^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:219:24: error: unknown type name 'uv_work_t'
void GenSaltAsyncAfter(uv_work_t* req) {
                       ^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:220:17: error: calling a protected constructor of class 'v8::HandleScope'
    HandleScope scope;
                ^
/Users/Cody/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:816:13: note: declared protected here
  V8_INLINE HandleScope() {}
            ^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:228:44: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
        argv[0] = Exception::Error(String::New(baton->error.c_str()));
                                   ~~~~~~~~^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:229:19: error: no matching function for call to 'Undefined'
        argv[1] = Undefined();
                  ^~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cody/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:305:28: note: candidate function not viable: requires single argument 'isolate', but no
      arguments were provided
  friend Handle<Primitive> Undefined(Isolate* isolate);
                           ^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:232:19: error: no matching function for call to 'Undefined'
        argv[0] = Undefined();
                  ^~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cody/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:305:28: note: candidate function not viable: requires single argument 'isolate', but no
      arguments were provided
  friend Handle<Primitive> Undefined(Isolate* isolate);
                           ^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:238:20: error: member reference type 'v8::Persistent<v8::Function>' is not a pointer; maybe you meant to use '.'?
    baton->callback->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), 2, argv);
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
                   .
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:238:22: error: no member named 'Call' in 'v8::Persistent<v8::Function, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> >'
    baton->callback->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), 2, argv);
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:238:36: error: no member named 'GetCurrent' in 'v8::Context'
    baton->callback->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), 2, argv);
                          ~~~~~~~~~^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:246:34: error: unknown type name 'Arguments'; did you mean 'v8::internal::Arguments'?
Handle<Value> GenerateSalt(const Arguments &args) {
                                 ^~~~~~~~~
                                 v8::internal::Arguments
/Users/Cody/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:127:7: note: 'v8::internal::Arguments' declared here
class Arguments;
      ^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:247:17: error: calling a protected constructor of class 'v8::HandleScope'
    HandleScope scope;
                ^
/Users/Cody/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:816:13: note: declared protected here
  V8_INLINE HandleScope() {}
            ^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:249:32: error: type 'const v8::internal::Arguments' does not provide a subscript operator
    const ssize_t rounds = args[0]->Int32Value();
                           ~~~~^~
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:250:30: error: type 'const v8::internal::Arguments' does not provide a subscript operator
    const int rand_len = args[1]->Int32Value();
                         ~~~~^~
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:251:58: error: type 'const v8::internal::Arguments' does not provide a subscript operator
    Local<Function> callback = Local<Function>::Cast(args[2]);
                                                     ~~~~^~
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:255:45: error: 'New' is a private member of 'v8::PersistentBase<v8::Function>'
    baton->callback = Persistent<Function>::New(callback);
                                            ^
/Users/Cody/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:572:23: note: declared private here
  V8_INLINE static T* New(Isolate* isolate, T* that);
                      ^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:255:57: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 1
    baton->callback = Persistent<Function>::New(callback);
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~         ^
/Users/Cody/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:572:3: note: 'New' declared here
  V8_INLINE static T* New(Isolate* isolate, T* that);
  ^
/Users/Cody/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8config.h:289:20: note: expanded from macro 'V8_INLINE'
# define V8_INLINE inline __attribute__((always_inline))
                   ^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:259:5: error: unknown type name 'uv_work_t'
    uv_work_t* req = new uv_work_t;
    ^
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:259:26: error: unknown type name 'uv_work_t'
    uv_work_t* req = new uv_work_t;
                         ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1067:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 13.4.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/richintime/ultimate-seed/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "bcrypt"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! bcrypt@0.7.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.7.7 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
```

Comment: very easy library https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-inzi

Answer (score 271, accepted):

The easy solution is just switch from the "bcrypt" npm module to [`bycryptjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs) or [`bcrypt-nodejs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-nodejs). It's the exact same API, but pure JS so no native add-ons to deal with.

```
npm install --save bcryptjs && npm uninstall --save bcrypt
```

Then change your `require` calls to "bcryptjs", but all your code otherwise can be unchanged.

Long term, I suspect at the moment bcrypt may not be ready for node v0.12.0 yet, but if not it will eventually be updated and ready.

Comment: 2.7x slower than python version

Comment: bcryptjs works for me. bcrypt-nodejs does NOT, though.

Comment: 2019 - looks like bcrypt-nodejs is no longer supported

Comment: its a fix, not THE fix. if you cant switch to node version of bcrypt, go for installing node-gyp (try npm i bcrypt npde-gyp --force) then trying npm i . it should build correctly.

Comment: I installed bcrypt-nodejs though it's already deprecated, and then removed it and installed bcrypt again. Like this, I Installed bcrypt successfully and it worked fine.

Comment: Can we somehow highlight this answer even more than just the tick? THIS is the answer :D I lost so many hours trying all the other "solutions". For the future HideThePain Harold: THIS is the answer.

Answer (score 43):

For windows install the following module:

```
npm install -g node-gyp
npm install --g --production windows-build-tools
```

Then try to install:

```
npm install bcrypt
```

Comment: This guy gives a perfect answer. other things are deprecated.

Comment: after all these things, you should also add `python` executable to your **environment variable PATH**, so that the installer finds it, seems it needs it to execute the installation properly.

Comment: You do that by right-clicking on Powershell and select "Run As Administrator"

Comment: Also be sure to close any other terminal (as I don't use Powershell by default) in order ton have `windows-build-tools` finish the installation. Thank you for this answer btw

Comment: Run as Administrator on Windows

Answer (score 14):

The accepted solution works, but bcryptjs is slower than python and C++ version.

If you still want bcrypt instead of bcryptjs, working solutions are the commands below, but they can also have their own problems.

```
✔️ npm install -g node-gyp
❌ npm install --g --production windows-build-tools
```

In Windows, the second command will try to install Visual Studio along with python and hence the problem arises because the Visual Studio installation takes a lot of time. Also it also hinders the installation of python. If you forget to run those commands as Administrator, then they will get installed at C:\Users\User.windows-build-tools which will still not work because node will search for python in C:\ or C:\Program Files. Hence these commands in some cases may increase your complications.

So the best idea for you is to ✔️install python manually for All Users. It is not necessary to add python to the environment path.

Then run:

```
✔️ npm install -g node-gyp
```

Now you are ready to install bcrypt:

```
npm install bcrypt
```

Answer (score 13):

On this command:

```
npm install --g --production windows-build-tools
```

You may have to run this in Powershell as administrator on your Windows machine.

You do that by right-clicking on Powershell and select "Run As Administrator"

Answer (score 8):

Upgrade to [bcrypt@5.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt)
`npm i bcrypt@5.0.0`

I am not getting errors on this newer version of bcrypt, older version gave different types of errors ranging from not able to install bcrypt to typescript type errors

Answer (score 4):

I just ran the following then tried the install and it worked:

```
npm install node-pre-gyp -g
```

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue on the server side( aws ubuntu 16.04).

I tried deleting node_module/bcrypt by `sudo rm -rf node_module/bcrypt` multiple times and reinstalled it again and again by various ways but still facing the same issue.

I checked node version with nvm and it was also showing stable (v10.11.0).

Finally, I tried.

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

and it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. I tried all above solutions, but nothing worked. bcrypt's official docs also node-gyp only works with stable node versions.

Answer (score 3):

On Mac OS, after a Xcode update, running `sudo gcc` and accepting Xcode's new license solved the problem!

Answer (score 2):

If you are on windows run powershell as administrator and use these commands.

```
npm install --g --production windows-build-tools
```

and then install bcrypt using

```
npm install --save bcrypt
```

Answer (score 2):

**Reason for Error** :
 Node maybe  can’t able to find the Python path on your system

**Solution**

**step: 1**  Rum command prompt as administrator
**step 2**   Install the package

```
  npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

It may take some while, keep patient

**step 3** Now install

```
npm install node-gyp
```

**Last step**  Now you are ready to Go

```
npm install bcrypt
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also having the same problem. The following commands helped me.

```
npm rebuild
```

then

```
npm install bcrypt
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this by running the command:
`sudo apt-get install -y build-essential python` and then `yarn add bcrypt`.

You can find the instructions here:

https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/wiki/Installation-Instructions

https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js

Answer (score 1):

I installed bcrypt-nodejs though it's already deprecated, and then removed it and installed bcrypt again. Like this, I Installed bcrypt successfully and it worked fine.

```
yarn add bcrypt-nodejs
yarn remove bcrypt-nodejs
yarn add bcrypt
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as I was installing a package from github that had an older version of bcrypt as a dependency. I just uninstalled the old bcrypt version and installed the newest version:

```
    npm uninstall bcrypt
    npm install bcrypt
```

Then, voila. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

if any of the above fails to work, do:

```
npm install node-gyp
```

Afterwards visit the official python download site [Official Python download link](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)

Install the latest version of python, make sure to check add python to path [image: add python to path]

After installation, do:

```
npm --save install bcrypt
```

Answer (score 0):

Running

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

installs all the tools you need to install bcrypt on Linux.
Then you can run

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

I had node version 12.18.3 and fixed the same by running `npm i bcrypt@3.0.6`

Answer (score 0):

********This helped me on my Ubuntu/Linux OS**********

Ensure Node.js and npm are up to date:
npm install -g n
n stable
npm install -g npm@latest

Delete node_modules and package-lock.json:
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json

Clean npm cache:
npm cache clean --force

Retry installing the packages:
npm install

Reinstall Node.js:
sudo apt remove nodejs npm

Install "bcrypt" Again:
npm i bcrypt

Answer (score 0):

npm uninstall --save bcrypt

and delete nodemodule folder and remove bcrypt dependency in package.json file

and use bcryptjs dependency

npm install --save bcryptjs

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem. Updating npm and try again (npm install -g npm usually). It fix the issue for me.