# Error installing bcrypt with NPM in meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, bcrypt

I've searched around for a couple of days trying to resolve this issue, and although people have had issues installing `bcrypt` with NPM, they don't appear to be like mine. For those of you finding this via Google, I suggest you also take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320201/error-installing-bcrypt-with-npm).

Now I get the following error, as do others, when installing `bcrypt`:

```
> bcrypt@0.8.7 install /home/william/bonsai/brain/src/hyperdev/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

/bin/sh: 1: node: not found
gyp: Call to 'node -e "require('nan')"' returned exit status 127 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/share/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:354:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-28-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/william/bonsai/brain/src/hyperdev/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.6
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
hyperdev@ /home/william/bonsai/brain/src/hyperdev
└── touch@1.0.0  extraneous

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-28-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "bcrypt"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.7 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs bcrypt
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/william/bonsai/brain/src/hyperdev/npm-debug.log
```

I have all of bcrypt's dependencies installed, so I am genuinely unsure of how to proceed. Here is the [npm debug log](https://gist.github.com/MadcowD/547d45f1cef2413fae713eaec1e5e14f) needed.

Comment: how do you fix this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a [known bug in Meteor](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7469).

Answer (score 1):

I use debian8.6-64bit.
I remove accounts-password and npm-bcrypt, and then I do

```
 meteor add npm-bcrypt  
 meteor npm install -g node-gyp  
 meteor npm install --save bcrypt  
 meteor npm install --save babel-runtime  
 meteor add accounts-password
```

Finally, I fix the bug. I'm not sure of its effectiveness, if you change order of command.