# Error in installing node package "bcrypt"

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

When I am running this command `npm install bcrypt` it is giving an error like this 
[image]

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Refer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320201/error-installing-bcrypt-with-npm

Comment: Try cleaning cache using npm cache clean

Comment: not working for me

Comment: You have python installed on your system?

Comment: yes i have python

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect.

Comment: Temporarily disable any AV/firewall and try again. Also try closing any open IDEs like WebStorm or Atom.