# How do I install bcrypt on Vagrant VM?

Tags: node.js, npm, bcrypt

When I try to install bcrypt I get this error

```
[vagrant@localhost example]$ npm install bcrypt --save
npm ERR! path /vagrant/example/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/minipass/node_modules/yallist/package.json.2764337951
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/vagrant/example/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/minipass/node_modules/yallist/package.json.2764337951'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2018-06-01T03_52_29_028Z-debug.log
```

I have a fresh install of the latest version of node and npm.
What should I do in similar cases?!

Comment: do you have package.json in that directory?

Comment: yes i have package.json

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by replacing "bcrypt" with "bcryptjs".

Source: [Error installing bcrypt with npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320201/error-installing-bcrypt-with-npm)

But still no way to install bcrypt

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue.

I think the root cause is that we can't install bcrypt in the /vagrant (special directory) where it links back to the host OS directory.

That directory is like a virtual directory. At such, if you want to solve it you could copy your project from /vagrant/example to an actual directory , ie. ~/example.

Then you would be able to install bcrypt from there.

** bcrypt is a library that has strong dependencies on the OS native environ