# Error while installing bycrpt in nodejs? whenever i run npm install install --save?

Tags: node.js, npm, window, bcrypt

````
> bcrypt@3.0.0 install C:\projects\alecadApi\node_modules\bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

`node-pre-gyp` WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v3.0.0/bcrypt_lib-v3.0.0-node-v57-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
`node-pre-gyp` WARN Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@3.0.0 and node@8.10.0 (node-v57 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
`C:\projects\alecadApi\node_modules\bcrypt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj(20,3)`: error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cp
p.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk
.
`gyp ERR!` build error
`gyp ERR!` stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\adity\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
`gyp ERR!` System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
`gyp ERR!` command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\adity\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\projects\\alecadApi\\node_modules\\bcrypt\\lib\\binding\\bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=C:\\projects\\alecadApi\\node_modules\\bcrypt\\lib\\binding" "--napi_version=1" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
`gyp ERR!` cwd C:\projects\alecadApi\node_modules\bcrypt
`gyp ERR`! node -v v8.10.0
`gyp ERR!` node-gyp -v v3.6.2
`gyp ERR!` not ok
`node-pre-gyp` ERR! build error
`node-pre-gyp` ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\adity\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\projects\alecadApi\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\projects\alecadApi\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding --napi_version=1 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\alecadApi\node_modules\bcrypt\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
`node-pre-gyp` ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
`node-pre-gyp` ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
`node-pre-gyp` ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
`node-pre-gyp` ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
`node-pre-gyp` ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
`node-pre-gyp` ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Projects\\alecadApi\\node_modules\\bcrypt\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
`node-pre-gyp` ERR! cwd C:\projects\alecadApi\node_modules\bcrypt
`node-pre-gyp` ERR! node -v v8.10.0
`node-pre-gyp` ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.2
`node-pre-gyp` ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\adity\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\projects\alecadApi\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\projects\alecadApi\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding --napi_version=1 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
`npm WARN` alecadApi@1.0.0 No repository field.
`npm WARN` optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
`npm WARN` notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

`npm ERR!` code ELIFECYCLE
`npm ERR!` errno 1
`npm ERR!` bcrypt@3.0.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
`npm ERR!` Exit status 1
npm ERR!
`npm ERR!` Failed at the bcrypt@3.0.0 install script.
`npm ERR!` This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

`npm ERR!` A complete log of this run can be found in:
`npm ERR!`     C:\Users\adity\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-07-07T10_51_34_631Z-debug.log```
````

Comment: just type **npm install bcrypt --save** in you terminal

Answer (score 5):

You should use

```
npm install --save bcrypt
```

for a proper installation.

By the way to use bcrypt you need python installed. If you want be python-independent use bcryptjs

```
npm install --save bcryptjs
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [this](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/wiki/Installation-Instructions#microsoft-windows)?

> Open powershell with administrator privileges and run this command,
>   then proceed with bcrypt installation.
>
> ```
> npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
> ```

Note: Wait until you see "**All Done!**" on the powershell window and then proceed to install the module.

Comment: This solved my problem perfectly. windows-build-tools supports all pure C++ addons for Node.js
Those are: node-sass, bcrypt, sqlite3, serialport, websocket, deasync, grpc, canvas, sharp, hiredis, leveldown, nodegit, zqm, ffi, libxmljs, iconv, ref, sleep, microtime, couchbase, bignum, kerberos, and ursa.

Comment: Happy to hear this. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to install bcrypt separately.

do `npm install bcrypt --save` and after this is done, run `npm install` again.

You can also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29320712/7049436) link for an answer to a similar question.

Alternatively, if this doesn't work, you can use `bcrypt-nodejs` or `bcryptjs` package.

Answer (score 2):

For some that may encounter that

## Case

If you were able to install correctly before. Then after upgrading your nodejs (for me i went from 11 to 12) you become unable.

If you get

```
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
```

an error like that. And then when you run `npm rebuild` you end up with other errors.

## Solution that can work (did for me)

**Remove completly** `bcrypt`. (remove from `package.json` then `npm install --save`).

Then reinstall again

```
npm install bcrypt --save
```

It installed correctly and build up with no problem.

(You may omit the remove part).

Comment: Spent over an hour trying to figure this out. YOur simple soln worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try with this version ..its working for me ...
`npm i bcrypt@3.0.6`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue because of my node js version `12.8.3`. I just changed my node version to `12.4.1`. And then try to install bcrypt using `npm i bcrypt`. Now its working fine for me.

Check/Download Different Node.js version from this [Link](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/)