# Bcrypt Installation error `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

Tags: node.js, npm-install, bcrypt

I am trying to Install bcrypt but getting errors. I have also tired to install older version but still getting same error.

I had tried to globally install dependancy NPM "node-gyp" but still getting errors.

Error screenshot
https://screencast.com/t/ADSe6khYE6pm

```
bcrypt@3.0.3 install /Users/rigalpatel/rect-practice/vidly-api-node/node_modules/bcrypt

node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v3.0.3/bcrypt_lib-v3.0.3-node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@3.0.3 and node@10.9.0 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: gyp failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:345:16)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:239:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/rigalpatel/rect-practice/vidly-api-node/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=/Users/rigalpatel/rect-practice/vidly-api-node/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding" "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v64"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/rigalpatel/rect-practice/vidly-api-node/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v10.9.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.7.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/rigalpatel/rect-practice/vidly-api-node/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/Users/rigalpatel/rect-practice/vidly-api-node/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess. (/Users/rigalpatel/rect-practice/vidly-api-node/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:250:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.5.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/rigalpatel/rect-practice/vidly-api-node/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/rigalpatel/rect-practice/vidly-api-node/node_modules/bcrypt
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.9.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/rigalpatel/rect-practice/vidly-api-node/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/Users/rigalpatel/rect-practice/vidly-api-node/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)
npm WARN vidly@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bcrypt@3.0.3 install: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@3.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Environments

OS: Mac 10.13.4
Node 10.9.0
NPM 6.2.0

Thanks

Comment: Delete your $HOME/.node-gyp i.e. /home/username/.node-gyp and reinstall it. let me know if it worked.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320201/error-installing-bcrypt-with-npm

Comment: I just Install xcode and configure it and bcrypt works.

Comment: I called sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools and then xcode-select --install.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is because of the `bcrypt` module dependency `node-gyp`. I suggest you use a library `bcryptjs` which has no dependencies and more downloads.

```
npm i bcryptjs --save
```

and dont forget to uninstall

```
npm uninstall bcrypt --save
```

On top of that `brcypt` has more dependecies like `python 2.x`. This will be also an issue on deployment also. It is better to use libraries with no dependencies.

Comment: This is excellent, especially when you are using docker alpine images that don't have python installed. Thank you

Comment: Node: While bcrypt.js is compatible to the C++ bcrypt binding, it is written in pure JavaScript and thus slower (about 30%), effectively reducing the number of iterations that can be processed in an equal time span.

Answer (score 1):

Try with below command

```
 npm install --save bcrypt-nodejs && npm uninstall --save bcrypt
```

Answer (score 0):

bcrypt-nodejs is no longer actively maintained. Please use bcrypt or bcryptjs, in this case use bcryptjs, it worked with me