# Installation failed bcrypt@4 on windows 10

Tags: node.js, express, bcrypt

I'm getting error when installing bcrypt via npm.

```
1237 verbose node v12.14.1
1238 verbose npm  v6.13.6
1239 error code ELIFECYCLE
1240 error errno 1
1241 error bcrypt@4.0.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
1241 error Exit status 1
1242 error Failed at the bcrypt@4.0.1 install script.
1242 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I would greatly appreciate your feedback.

Comment: just use [bcryptjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs)  package instead of bcrypt package. It has the same functionality without installation problems.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Yes, bcryptjs hasn't dependency issues but, I think bcryptjs slower then the bcrypt. I got the fine answer. Please refer this link. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320201/error-installing-bcrypt-with-npm)