# i am getting the following error while installing material-UI in vs code with npm WHAT SHOULD I DO?

Tags: reactjs, npm, error-handling

npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!   @material-ui/core@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\ayush tawar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ayush tawar\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-06-10T07_31_54_848Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\ayush tawar\OneDrive\Desktop\twitter clone>

Answer (score 0):

Please try to do like this
`npm cache clean`

and then

```
npm install -g node-gyp
npm install --g --production windows-build-tools
```

[Error installing bcrypt with npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320201/error-installing-bcrypt-with-npm)

You can also add `--verbose` flag at the end of `npm install` which will show more
information about this issue.
if second command will not work, then you should install python to your pc and install this one.

```
npm install --g  windows-build-tools
```

I believe if you will use ubuntu or mac os, it will be resolved maybe.

Or it could be node version issue, please upgrade node version.

Answer (score 0):

The package is not up to date for react 18.
Just install it with --legacy-peer-deps, this will override the error checking.

npm install @material-ui/core --legacy-peer-deps