# Not able to install project dependencies NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I am trying to install dependency in a project but getting this error. I already upgraded all dependencies and versions of npm but that's not working for me.

**Package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "task",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "connect-mongo": "^3.2.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.4.0",
    "express-flash": "^0.0.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mongodb": "^4.9.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.0.5",
    "multer": "^1.4.3",
    "node": "^16.6.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.13",
    "open": "^8.4.0",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "simplebar": "^5.3.5"
  }
}
```

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error installing bcrypt with npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320201/error-installing-bcrypt-with-npm)

Comment: Remove the global flag in your command. Just do `npm i` or `npm install` in the directory where the `package.json` exists.