getting this error while installing bcrypt how to solve this
im trying to load this repository on my pc , it was created by me on my other pc , now when im installing it on my older  pc , whenever i try to install the bcrypt module an error keeps showing up all the other dependencies of the project are getting installed but only when i try to install bcrypt the error shows up
i have tried almost everything i found on the internet , i tried clearing npm cache, reinstalling node, reinstalled  the repository in new folder , downloaded pyhton installed windows build tool  but still the error is not resolved
npm error code 1
npm error path C:\Users\HP\Documents\Hostel\backend\node_modules\bcrypt
npm error command failed
npm error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build     
npm error Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
npm error   nothing.c
npm error   win_delay_load_hook.cc
npm error   nothing.vcxproj -> C:\Users\HP\Documents\Hostel\backend\node_modules\bcrypt\build\Release\\nothing.lib
npm error   blowfish.cc
npm error   bcrypt.cc
npm error   bcrypt_node.cc
npm error c:\users\hp\documents\hostel\backend\node_modules\bcrypt\src\bcrypt_node.cc(99): error C2666: 'Napi::CallbackInfo::operator []': 2 overloads have similar conversions [C:\Users\HP\Documents\Hostel\backend\node_modules\bcrypt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]


See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320201/error-installing-bcrypt-with-npm
