# Error during node-gyp build and bcrypt installation

Tags: node.js, bcrypt, node-gyp

I was trying to install bcrypt in smartos of joyent using `npm install bcrypt` but getting an error. Then with help of the right answer of a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153317/cannot-install-bcrypt-node-js-module-on-centos-server) I tried but again stuck due to following error while executing `node-gyp build`.

What could be problem and how to get out from it?

```
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@0.13.0
gyp info using node@0.10.24 | sunos | x64
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/opt/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/which/which.js:43:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/opt/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/which/which.js:46:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /opt/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/which/which.js:57:16
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
gyp ERR! System SunOS 5.11
gyp ERR! command "node" "/opt/local/bin/node-gyp" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/admin/workbench/dev/node.bcrypt.js
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.24
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: Are you sure you have make, gcc, g++, python 2.x, and other build tools installed (properly)?

Comment: After installation of gmake (for make) and gcc47-4.7.3nb1 (for g++) in smartos now I am able to install bcrypt using npm directly (npm install bcrypt). No need to workaround as suggested in the link in my query. Thanks mscdex for the sugession.