# Node project Project dependence install failed

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

when installing dependence for node project given error.

i use this command

```
npm install --save mongojs restify bcrypt morgan
```

this is the error

[image]

please help...!!

Comment: seems error in bcrypt first run `npm install --save mongojs restify  morgan` after that follow this accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153317/cannot-install-bcrypt-node-js-module-on-centos-server/20895568#20895568

Comment: Do you have [`node-gyp`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-gyp) installed globally? Packages that are defined as [native addons](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html), like [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bcrypt), require being compiled during installation using it. You'll also need Python 2 and a C/C++ compiler (Visual C++ for Windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help some one.

Update to

```
 Visual Studio 2010 
 to 
 Visual Studio 2010 S1
```

source from : [Blog](http://wishmesh.com/2011/04/fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-ammintrin-h-no-such-file-or-directory/)